# Showing coercitivity of bilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis

For $u,\varphi \in W_0^{k,p}((0,1))$ we define
$a(u,\varphi)= \int_0^1u'\varphi'+\frac{1}{2}u'\varphi d\mu$. Now I'm supposed to show that there is $c>0$ such that $a(u,u)\geq c\|u\|_{W_0^{k,p}}$ for all $u \in W_0^{k,p}$. I've tried poincaré and partial integration, but I really don't know, how to continue. Thanks!